# Using different intervals for carousels in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm currently stuck at the problem, that I have two carousels in my Bootstrap Document, each with a unique id and class (#myCarousel-1, #myCarousel-2 / .carousel-1, .carousel-2).
I target the carousels with the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myCarousel-1').carousel({
        interval: 2000
    })
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myCarousel-2').carousel({
        interval: false
    })
</script>
```

The problem is that neither the id or the class target the specific divs. Both carousels start to slide in intervals. Any ideas how to avoid this?

PS: I changed the ids and classes after this tip: [Is it possible to have multiple Twitter Bootstrap carousels on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521257/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-twitter-bootstrap-carousels-on-one-page)

Answer (score 2):

You could say I accidently found the solution. Write the following in your html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#myCarousel-1').carousel({
            interval: 2000
        })
        $('#myCarousel-2').carousel({
            interval: false
        })
    });
</script>
```

And you are good to go.