# Bootstrap carousel with thumbnails foreach not working after Change

Tags: javascript, c#, html, css, asp.net-core

> My friends, I use this code for the product image gallery, but it does not work manually, where is the problem? I use this code, but the thumb part of the photos does not move the photos correctly and does not work?

```
                        <!-- Sorry! Lightbox doesn't work - yet. -->

                        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner">
                            @foreach (var obj in galleries.Select((item, index) => new { item, index }))
                            {
                                <div class="carousel-item @(obj.index==0?"item active":"item")" data-slide-number="@obj.item.GalleryId">
                                    <img src="/ProductFile/Gallery/@obj.item.ImageName" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." data-remote="https://source.unsplash.com/tXqVe7oO-go/" data-type="image" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery">
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Carousel Navigation -->
                    <div id="carousel-thumbs" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <div class="row mx-0">

                                    @foreach (var item in galleries)
                                    {
                                        <div id="carousel-selector-@item.GalleryId" class="thumb col-4 col-sm-2 px-1 py-2" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="@item.GalleryId">
                                            <img src="/ProductFile/Gallery/@item.ImageName" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
                                        </div>
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-thumbs" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-thumbs" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

> I use this code, but the thumb part of the photos does not move the photos correctly and does not work?

```
<script>
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval: false
    });
    $('#carousel-thumbs').carousel({
        interval: false
    });

    // handles the carousel thumbnails
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752187/bootstrap-carousel-with-thumbnails-multiple-carousel
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click(function () {
        var id_selector = $(this).attr('id');
        var id = parseInt(id_selector.substr(id_selector.lastIndexOf('-') + 1));
        $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
    });
    // Only display 3 items in nav on mobile.
    if ($(window).width() < 575) {
        $('#carousel-thumbs .row div:nth-child(4)').each(function () {
            var rowBoundary = $(this);
            $('<div class="row mx-0">').insertAfter(rowBoundary.parent()).append(rowBoundary.nextAll().addBack());
        });
        $('#carousel-thumbs .carousel-item .row:nth-child(even)').each(function () {
            var boundary = $(this);
            $('<div class="carousel-item">').insertAfter(boundary.parent()).append(boundary.nextAll().addBack());
        });
    }
    // Hide slide arrows if too few items.
    if ($('#carousel-thumbs .carousel-item').length < 2) {
        $('#carousel-thumbs [class^=carousel-control-]').remove();
        $('.machine-carousel-container #carousel-thumbs').css('padding', '0 5px');
    }
    // when the carousel slides, auto update
    $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
        var id = parseInt($(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-slide-number'));
        $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').removeClass('selected');
        $('[id=carousel-selector-' + id + ']').addClass('selected');
    });
    // when user swipes, go next or previous
    $('#myCarousel').swipe({
        fallbackToMouseEvents: true,
        swipeLeft: function (e) {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('next');
        },
        swipeRight: function (e) {
            $('#myCarousel').carousel('prev');
        },
        allowPageScroll: 'vertical',
        preventDefaultEvents: false,
        threshold: 75
    });

    //$(document).on('click', '[data-toggle="lightbox"]', function(event) {
    //  event.preventDefault();
    //  $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    //});


    $('#myCarousel .carousel-item img').on('click', function (e) {
        var src = $(e.target).attr('data-remote');
        if (src) $(this).ekkoLightbox();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I would suggest you try to debug your JQuery code for that thumbnail part. See whether it shows any error in the browser console? the above posted code is not complete so I am not able to run it successfully. Could you please inform us what exact behavior you are seeing after code modification? What exactly did you modify in the code?

Comment: I have a problem with my thumb... the problem is that when I use the ring, my thumb doesn't work properly... I'll show you the demo.

Comment: var id = parseInt(id_selector.substr(id_selector.lastIndexOf('-') == id_selector));

Comment: https://vishartech.com/ShowProduct/1002

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the site URL. I have tried to check your code and found some issues.

You could try to make the changes below may help to fix the issue.

1. I noticed that `data-slide-to` values started from 4. It should be started from 0.

```html
<div id="carousel-selector-4" class="thumb col-4 col-sm-2 px-1 py-2" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0">
<img src="./درنیکا گیفت _ کاسه_files/39d5e36e372942f2b2d284c0a8e1b2b8.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
</div>
<div id="carousel-selector-5" class="thumb col-4 col-sm-2 px-1 py-2 selected" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1">
<img src="./درنیکا گیفت _ کاسه_files/3d030297d7914f67b12d775f01e562fb.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
</div>
<div id="carousel-selector-6" class="thumb col-4 col-sm-2 px-1 py-2" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2">
<img src="./درنیکا گیفت _ کاسه_files/df7abc7f67654bce87bd5191d98f9680.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
</div>
<div id="carousel-selector-7" class="thumb col-4 col-sm-2 px-1 py-2" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3">
<img src="./درنیکا گیفت _ کاسه_files/7a87779468ff4b958d715d6a39d08cdf.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="...">
</div>
```

2. Below Jquery code is causing the issue. Try to comment/ remove it.

```js
$('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click(function () {
            var id_selector = $(this).attr('id');
            var id = parseInt(id_selector.substr(id_selector.lastIndexOf('-') == id_selector));
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
});
```

**Output:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkYX0.jpg

Further, I suggest you add an arrow button for the Next and Previous actions.

```html
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, my dear friend, for your time... but I copied that part of the code, the slider stopped working... I use the foreach loop... the ID of the slider is dynamic.

Comment: Modifying the code as per suggestion above should not break it. Could you please inform us where exactly you have modified which part of code? Further, please check the browser console for errors after modification. It may give the idea why carousel stopped working.