# bootstrap carousel problems when two slide in the same page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

When I use multiple or two bootstrap carousel in the same page, it will cause the problem. It is the first prev and next button will control two bootstrap carousel slides and another one prev and next does not work. How to solve?? Or I need to change another one to use another option??

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">

          <div class="inner-box relative">
            <h2 class="title-2">Your Interested Items 

                        <a id="nextItem" class="link  pull-right carousel-nav"> <i class="icon-right-open-big"></i></a>
             <a id="prevItem" class="link pull-right carousel-nav"> <i class="icon-left-open-big"></i> </a>

            </h2>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="no-margin item-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <div class="item">.................
...........................................

<div class="container">
      <div class="row">

          <div class="inner-box relative">
            <h2 class="title-2">Your Interested Items 

                        <a id="nextItem" class="link  pull-right carousel-nav"> <i class="icon-right-open-big"></i></a>
             <a id="prevItem" class="link pull-right carousel-nav"> <i class="icon-left-open-big"></i> </a>

            </h2>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="no-margin item-carousel owl-carousel owl-theme">
                    <div class="item">.................
...........................................
```

Answer (score 0):

You might need to change `href` of `prev` and `next` targeting its parent `carousel`.  That href value is how bootstrap determines which to slide. So you will need to change the following:

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

And for the second carousel:

```
<a class="carousel-control left" href="#carousel-2" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
<a class="carousel-control right" href="#carousel-2" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
```

**[SOURCE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10521806/2065039)**