# Autoplay Carousels?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, owl-carousel

I'm very, VERY new to Javascript. I'm trying to get both sliders to autoplay slowly on the same page:

[Live site](http://suncoastdiesel-com.3dcartstores.com/) - The main carousel and the the smaller one near the bottom with logos.

The smaller one is using OwlCarousel and I know I can add `autoPlay: 3000,` - but can't on one page because of the other one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to have multiple Twitter Bootstrap carousels on one page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521257/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-twitter-bootstrap-carousels-on-one-page)

Comment: @PetarDonchevMarinov Similar, but I need them to autoplay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main slider uses **[swiper](http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/)**.

In your HTML code you have script:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.arrow-right',
    prevButton: '.arrow-left',
    // effect: 'cube',
    keyboardControl: true,
    parallax: true,
    speed: 600,
    spaceBetween: 0
});
```

You need to add `autoplay` (small `p` in this case) option to that for example:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
    paginationClickable: '.swiper-pagination',
    nextButton: '.arrow-right',
    prevButton: '.arrow-left',
    // effect: 'cube',
    keyboardControl: true,
    parallax: true,
    speed: 600,
    spaceBetween: 0,
    autoplay: 8000
});
```

---

Your logos carousel uses **[owlCarousel](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/)**

In you JavaScript file (`script.js`) you have to add autoPlay (capital `P`) option to `.brand-carousel`.

```
var owl= $(".brand carousel");
owl.owlCarousel({
  navigation:false,
  pagination:false,
  items:8,
  itemsTablet:[768,4],
  itemsMobile:[400,2],
  autoPlay: 3000
});
```