# How to place two bootstrap carousels in the same page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

[image: Here is a mockup image of what I am trying to do]I am trying to use two bootstrap carousels on the same page. The following is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!--BOOTSTRAP LINKS FOR CAROUSEL-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--BOOTSTRAP LINKS-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <!--START OF NAVBAR-->
    <div class="nav-box">
        <br>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <img src="logo.png" id="logo"></img>
                </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">ABOUT S</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <!--END OF NAVBAR-->
    <!--START OF BOOTSTRAP CAROUSEL-->
    <section class="section-white">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <!-- Indicators -->
                <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                </ol>
                <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                <div class="carousel-inner" style="width:100%; height: 500px !important;">
                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="a.jpg" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="b.jpg" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="c.jpg" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h2>Heading</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Controls -->
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!--END OF BOOTSTRAP CAROUSEL-->
    <!--START OF RADIO BAR-->
    <div class="radio-bar">
        <div class="text1">
            <h3 id="text1-line1">streams</h3>
            <h4 id="text1-line2">shows</h4>
        </div>
        <div id="audio">
            <audio controls>
                <source src="viper.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls">
            </audio>
        </div>
        <div id="podcast-box">
            <img src="icon.png" id="image"></img>
            <p id="pheading">casts</p>
        </div>
        <div id="blue-box">
            <img src="blue.svg" id="blue-box-image"></img>
            <p id="blue-box-heading">show</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END OF RADIO BAR-->
    <!--START OF ABOUT US BAR-->
    <div class="about-us">
        <h3 id="heading">ABOUT</h3>
        <p id="para">*******</p>
        <div class="image-box">
            <img src="image.jpg" id="image"></img>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--END OF ABOUT US BAR-->
    <!--START OF VIDEO CAROUSEL-->
    <div class="container" id="container">
        <div class="row" id="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" id="carousel">
                    <ol class="carousel-indicators" id="carousel-indicators">
                        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active" id="action"></li>
                        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                        <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                    </ol>
                    <!-- Carousel items -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="item active" id="item-active">
                            <div class="row" id="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--.row-->
                        </div>
                        <!--.item-->
                        <div class="item" id="item">
                            <div class="row" id="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--.row-->
                        </div>
                        <!--.item-->
                        <div class="item" id="item">
                            <div class="row" id="row">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!--.row-->
                        </div>
                        <!--.item-->
                    </div>
                    <!--.carousel-inner-->
                    <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control" id="carousel-control">‹</a>
                    <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control" id="carousel-control">›</a>
                </div>
                <!--.Carousel-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--.container-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Carousel').carousel({
            interval: 5000
        })
    });
    </script>
    <!--END OF VIDEO CAROUSEL-->
</body>
</html>
```

I changed the class names to id, because it was overlapping with the previous carousel. Even after doing that the second carousel is overlapping with the element just before it, and the right navigation arrow is not appearing.

I checked the following link: [Is it possible to have multiple Twitter Bootstrap carousels on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521257/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-twitter-bootstrap-carousels-on-one-page/10521806#10521806).

Here it says that the navigation href should point to different ids, which I have done.  But I am still getting the problem.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You need to have different id/classes, it wont work if the one is class: "carousel" and the other one is id: "carousel". They need to be different.

Comment: @Seb I had changed the class names. All of them. like carousel-2, etc. But that didn't help.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'overlapping'? Do you mean the names are the same, or are the carousels visually overlapping each other?

Comment: @Steve Doson, alright i have had this problem before and there was like one class i forgot to change that messed up everything. Its kinda hard to figure out when i don't have an working example.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware yes visually overlapping.

Comment: Can i see your whole html page?

Comment: Since your code is incomplete I cannot reproduce what you're seeing. Therefore it will be hard to know what is going on.... basically the same as Seb says... :-)

Comment: You could use the developer tools to inspect your code, and find out what CSS does what. On a Windows desktop simply press F12 and the tools should appear.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have updated my code with the entire html now. If you would kindly have a look.

Comment: Now I am missing all of the CSS.

Comment: @Seb I have added the entire html page. Please have a look.

Comment: @SteveDoson look at my answer :)

Comment: What I mean is that I don't have the 'style.css' file that is linked to your html page.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I have a demo fiddle here with just the two carousels https://jsfiddle.net/sy2m4rvo/ I am basically trying to implement this https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4D82 and this https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/simple-responsive-carousel in one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Last edit** There you go, i added the carousel function to the thumbnail for the 2nd carousel. :)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#myCarousel3').carousel({
        interval: 1000000
    });

    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
            interval: 3000
    });
    $('#myCarousel2').carousel({
            interval: 2000
    });

    $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

    //Handles the carousel thumbnails
    $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
            var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
            var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
            var id = parseInt(id);
            $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
    });


    // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
    $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
            var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
    });
});
```

```css
#myCarousel {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.thumbnail {
  border: none;
}
.thumbnail-modifier {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.thumbnails {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.thumbnails-center {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.row-fluid {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
#myCarousel3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.row-center {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.carousel-control-modifier {
  background-image: none !important;
  color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="container">
<div id="main_area">
  <!-- Slider -->
  <div class="row">
      <div id="slider">
          <!-- Top part of the slider -->
          <div class="row">
              <div id="carousel-bounding-box">
                  <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel2">
                      <!-- Carousel items -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=one"></div>

                          <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=two"></div>

                          <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=three"></div>

                          <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=four"></div>

                          <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=five"></div>


                      </div><!-- Carousel nav -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>
  </div><!--/Slider-->
</div>
  <div class="row">
      <div id="slider">
          <!-- Top part of the slider -->
          <div class="row">
              <div id="carousel-bounding-box">
                  <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                      <!-- Carousel items -->
                      <div class="carousel-inner">
                          <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=one"></div>

                          <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=two"></div>

                          <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=three"></div>

                          <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=four"></div>

                          <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                          <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=five"></div>


                      </div><!-- Carousel nav -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                      </a>
                  </div>
              </div>
      </div>
  </div><!--/Slider-->
</div>

<div class="">
  <div id="myCarousel3" class="carousel slide">            
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

  <div class="item active">
      <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="row-center">
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four"></a>
          </div>
      </div><!--/row-fluid-->
  </div><!--/item-->

  <div class="item">
      <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="row-center">
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=extra"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=extra"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=extra"></a>
          </div>
      </div><!--/row-fluid-->
  </div><!--/item-->

  <div class="item">
      <div class="row-fluid">
          <div class="row-center">
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=extra"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=extra"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=extra"></a>
              <a class="thumbnail cursor thumbnail-modifier" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=extra"></a>
          </div>
      </div><!--/row-fluid-->
  </div><!--/item-->

  </div><!--/carousel-inner-->

      <a class="left carousel-control carousel-control-modifier" href="#myCarousel3" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control carousel-control-modifier" href="#myCarousel3" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div><!--/myCarousel-->

</div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have been trying to change the size of the thumbnails and reduce the distance between the thumbnails and the navigation arrows. While I have been able to increase the distance between the thumbnails with padding, I wonder how can I alter the size of the squares and the distance between them and the navigation arrows.

Comment: To change the thumbnails you need to change the size here http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one, if you want it to be 220x120 you just put that in instead. To change the distance between the thumbnails and navigations arrows you need to add this to the .carousel-control-modifier css. Now its 15% width, if you want the arrows closer, change it to width: 25%; or something. @SteveDoson

Comment: There is a certain problem that I am noticing. When the page is open for a considerable time, the carousels are freezing up. Any idea why that is happening?

Answer (score 2):

**Update 3:** Here you go, pretty sure this is what you wanted, you need to copy all the code to your own server and it should work! :)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#myCarousel').carousel({
      interval: 3000
  });
  $('#myCarousel2').carousel({
      interval: 2000
  });

  $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

  //Handles the carousel thumbnails
  $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
      var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
      var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
      var id = parseInt(id);
      $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
  });


  // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
  $('#myCarousel').on('slid', function (e) {
      var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
      $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
  });
});
```

```css
#myCarousel {
  margin-top: 30px;
}
.thumbnail {
  border: none;
}
.thumbnails {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}
.thumbnails-center {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href='test2.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<div class="container">
  <div id="main_area">
      <!-- Slider -->
      <div class="row">
          <div id="slider">
              <!-- Top part of the slider -->
              <div class="row">
                  <div id="carousel-bounding-box">
                      <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel2">
                          <!-- Carousel items -->
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=one"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=two"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=three"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=four"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=five"></div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Carousel nav -->
                          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel2" role="button" data-slide="next">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--/Slider-->
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div id="slider">
              <!-- Top part of the slider -->
              <div class="row">
                  <div id="carousel-bounding-box">
                      <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                          <!-- Carousel items -->
                          <div class="carousel-inner">
                              <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=one"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=two"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=three"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=four"></div>
                              <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x546&text=five"></div>
                          </div>
                          <!-- Carousel nav -->
                          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                          </a>
                          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                              <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                          </a>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <!--/Slider-->
          <div class="row hidden-phone" id="slider-thumbs">
              <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
              <div class="thumbnails">
                  <div class="thumbnails-center">
                      <a class="thumbnail cursor" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one"></a>
                      <a class="thumbnail cursor" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two"></a>
                      <a class="thumbnail cursor" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three"></a>
                      <a class="thumbnail cursor" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four"></a>
                      <a class="thumbnail cursor" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five"></a>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>    
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: When I will add your snippet, do I change all the class names ?

Comment: You need to change so that the first carousel has the   id of "Carousel" and the other carousel has all the ids of "Carousel2" where you need it to be that id.

Comment: If you would please have a look at this link [https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4D82], I am trying to implement this carousel in the same page with the my first carousel. But I have no idea why the entire thing is turning into a mess. If you want I can update my code.

Comment: You can have a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sy2m4rvo/ It has both the carousels I want.

Comment: I don't understand how you want the finished carousel to look, can you draw a fast mock up on how you want it? @SteveDoson

Comment: I have given the mockup now. Please do have a look. :)

Comment: There you go! Look at my answer :) @SteveDoson

Comment: Thank you so much! You have been a life saver! :)  However, I also want the one, two, three, four thumbnails to be like a carousel. In the image you can see that I have placed arrows for them as well.

Comment: No problem! :) Oh yeah i see, i just left my pc so i will add that later today if you can't figure it out. @SteveDoson

Answer (score 0):

You can just change Carousel ID for making these sliders unique. Please see the attached code as an example.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>





<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="demo1" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators/dots -->
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo1" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>



<!-- Carousel -->
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators/dots -->
  <div class="carousel-indicators">
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="1"></button>
    <button type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide-to="2"></button>
  </div>
  
  <!-- The slideshow/carousel -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" class="d-block" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls/icons -->
  <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#demo" data-bs-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </button>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```