# Bootstrap carousels freezing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I had asked a previous question regarding multiple bootstrap carousels and had received an absolutely fine code from a Stack Overflow user.

You can see the code here: [How to place two bootstrap carousels in the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103798/how-to-place-two-bootstrap-carousels-in-the-same-page) Under **Last Edit**

I am using the same code provided by the user. But the problem is the carousels are freezing up when the page stays open for long.

By freezing up I mean the first slider, stops sliding after the specified interval. If I manually click on the navigation button, it slides.

For the second carousel and the thumbnails, the problem is that when I am clicking on a thumbnail, the respective image is not showing up in the second carousel.

No amount of refreshing or copy pasting the code into the page helps.

There are obviously other elements on my page too, but none have jquery or similar class names. So overlapping of class names or id names is ruled out.

Where is the problem?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: just noticed that on your second carousel, the thumbnail images you want to display (extra) have the same ids, using id's on elements should be identical, especially when your're giving them some actions or modifications in your scripts. check this: https://imgur.com/a/MiBc5

Comment: @jhek Even if I am not clicking on the extra, the problem persists. If I click on one, two, three, four or five I am facing the same thing.

Comment: that's weird, ive tried you code here, check this out. https://jsfiddle.net/tqtva7r2/1/ the only thing that i found that's not working is those "extra" images.

Comment: @jhek It works fine initially. Only when the page is open for a really long time, do they freeze up. That's the most weirdest thing.

Comment: by what you mean "really long time" how long? have you tried to check you're console? are there any errors? btw, can you edit your post and include what code are you exactly have, and how many sliders btw do you really intend to use?

Comment: @jhek I have checked the console. It doesn't show any errors.

Comment: @jhek Here is the fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/vpjzomv0/ please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here you're missing a `});` in your code, as I review your jsfiddle, this is a terminator for this `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`. Check the jsfiddle now [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vpjzomv0/1/).

Comment: I copy pasted the jquery but the problem still persists. I fail to understand how it is working in the fiddle but not here.

Comment: @SteveDoson i guess you should observe proper declarations of libraries to your head markups. Pls include the entire code you have above so we can review it.

Answer (score 0):

Add the ‘data-interval’ on the first line of code

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000"></div>
```

1000 is 1 second, and 3000 is 3 seconds. You can replace ‘3000’ with your desired slider speed.