# One Bootstrap carousel wrongly mixing photos with another bootstrap carousel from the same page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I added 2 bootstrap 5 carousels on the same page, added unique ID to each of them, but sadly the second carousel mixes photos with the first carousel. It takes 2 photos from the previous slide. Adding unique ID's to each carousel didn't change the situation.
Is there a solution to this?
I checked also this post but it didn't help:
[How to place two bootstrap carousels in the same page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103798/how-to-place-two-bootstrap-carousels-in-the-same-page)

```HTML
<!-- Bootstrap carousel 1 -->
    <div class="container text-center my-3 mb-5">
                    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-between">
                        <div id="Carousel-1" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-img">
                                                <img src="./images/person1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-img-overlay"><strong>John Smith</strong>
                                                <p class="mt-0 me-2" style="font-size: 13px;">Administration</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-img">
                                                <img src="./images/person2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-img-overlay"><strong>Sarah Smith</strong>
                                                <p class="mt-0 me-2" style="font-size: 13px;">Finance</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-img">
                                                <img src="./images/person3.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-img-overlay"><strong>Roger Kensinghton</strong>
                                                <p class="mt-0 me-2" style="font-size: 13px;">Security</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-img">
                                                <img src="./images/person4.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-img-overlay"><strong>Kelly Parker</strong>
                                                <p class="mt-0 me-2" style="font-size: 13px;">Design</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#Carousel-1" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#Carousel-1" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

<!-- Bootstrap carousel 2 -->
    <div class="container text-center my-3 mb-5 carousel2">
                    <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-between">
                        <div id="Carousel-2" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
                            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                                <div class="carousel-item active">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-img">
                                                <img src="./images/woman1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-img-bottom"><strong>Jane Dow</strong>
                                                <p class="mt-0 me-2" style="font-size: 13px;">CEO AXA Group</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-img">
                                                <img src="./images/man1.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-img-bottom"><strong>Dave Johnson</strong>
                                                <p class="mt-0 me-2" style="font-size: 13px;">Marketing Manager Johnson's & Co</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-img">
                                                <img src="./images/man2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-img-bottom"><strong>Roger Smith</strong>
                                                <p class="mt-0 me-2" style="font-size: 13px;">CEO Hi-Tech Intl.</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <div class="card-img">
                                                <img src="./images/woman2.jpg" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="card-img-bottom"><strong>Diana Russel</strong>
                                                <p class="mt-0 me-2" style="font-size: 13px;">Manager Creativity Hub</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#Carousel-2" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
                                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                            <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#Carousel-2" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
                                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

```JavaScript
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')

items.forEach((el) => {
    const minPerSlide = 3
    let next = el.nextElementSibling
    for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
        if (!next) {
            // wrap carousel by using first child
          next = items[0]
        }
        let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
        el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
        next = next.nextElementSibling
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you use .carousal selector and class is present in both carousals use ids instead of class #Carousel-1 or #Carousel-2

```
let items = document.querySelectorAll('#Carousel-1 .carousel-item')
```

Comment: My Pleasure ... Best of Luck