# Use two Bootstrap carousels on the same page - One single and one with multiple items on one slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

### I am using two different Bootstrap Carousels on the same page on my wordpress website

One of them is a normal carousel with one item on each slider. The second carousel has three items on each slide and only slides one item each time, like so:

[1, 2, 3] .. [2, 3, 4] .. [3, 4, 1]

The first carousel is working fine, but the second carousel is not.

The second carousel isn't showing the first item after the last one. It is showing two empty items first and then does a weird "jump" (you can see if you visit my website in the URL below).

This is what happens basically:

[1, 2, 3] .. [2, 3, 4] .. [3, 4, blank] .. [4, blank, blank] ..and then jumps back to start.. [1, 2, 3]

However, it is working without any issues if I put the carousel on a page where theres is no other bootstrap carousel! So **the problem is in the conflict with the first carousel**.

I've been googling and looking at stackoverflow for an answer on my particular situation for many hours without luck.

All the old questions has been for people using two normal carousels and not with a "multislider" involved.

**I use unique identifiers for the carousels**.

### Links to my carousels:

You can see my two carousels in action here (and inspect the code): https://devolt.se/.

Here you can see my second carousel on a test page (it works fine here): https://devolt.se/test/

Comment: Are you using unique identifiers for each carousel?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521257/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-twitter-bootstrap-carousels-on-one-page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to have multiple Twitter Bootstrap carousels on one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521257/is-it-possible-to-have-multiple-twitter-bootstrap-carousels-on-one-page)

Comment: Yes I am using unique identifiers

Comment: Sorry but that answer didn't help me. I have looked at dosens of question/answers like that to try and find some different detail that could help me..

Comment: I might add one thing that I found when I troubleshooted my code in a local dev. The code "totalItems = ${.carousel-items}.length" for the second carousel is counting 10 slides, which means it calculates the slides in both carousels (6 slides in the second carousel and 4 slides in the first).

But I couldn't find a solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

While you do have different identifiers, you don't use them to initiate the each carousel separately. Also, you use `slide.bs.carousel` event on `#carousel-reviews`, but then within the scoped function, you apply code to both carousels' items, and that is what is causing that weird behavior.

See your code:

```
<script>
// Stop portfolio slider from auto looping
$('.carousel').carousel({ //HERE YOU INITIATE BOTH CAROUSELS AT SAME TIME
  interval: false
})
</script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    /*
        Carousel
    */
    $('#carousel-reviews').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

        var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var idx = $e.index();
        var itemsPerSlide = 3;
        var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;

        if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
            var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
            for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
                // append slides to end
                if (e.direction=="left") {
                    $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
                }
                else {
                    $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Try initiating them separately, and then manipulate `.carousel-item` specifically for each carousel:

```
<script>
    // Stop portfolio slider from auto looping
   $('#carousel-portfolio').carousel({
      interval: false
    })
    $('#carousel-reviews').carousel({ 
      interval: false
    })
    </script>

    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        /*
            Carousel
        */
        $('#carousel-reviews').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

            var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
            var idx = $e.index();
            var itemsPerSlide = 3;
            //also, here, specify selection only to #carousel-reviews: 
            var carouselItems = $('#carousel-reviews .carousel-item');
            var totalItems = carouselItems.length; 

            if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
                var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
                for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
                    // append slides to end
                    if (e.direction=="left") {
                        carouselItems.eq(i).appendTo('#carousel-reviews .carousel-inner');
                    }
                    else {
                        carouselItems.eq(0).appendTo('#carousel-reviews .carousel-inner');
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        //and if you need to do this to #carousel-portfolio too: 

       $('#carousel-portfolio').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {

            var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
            var idx = $e.index();
            var itemsPerSlide = 3;
            //also, here, specify selection only to #carousel-reviews: 
            var carouselItems = $('#carousel-portfolio .carousel-item');
            var totalItems = carouselItems.length; 

            if (idx >= totalItems-(itemsPerSlide-1)) {
                var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
                for (var i=0; i<it; i++) {
                    // append slides to end
                    if (e.direction=="left") {
                        carouselItems.eq(i).appendTo('#carousel-portfolio .carousel-inner');
                    }
                    else {
                        carouselItems.eq(0).appendTo('#carousel-portfolio .carousel-inner');
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks niklaz, but for some reason this is not doing the trick! Now when you "slide through" the second carousel, the content from the first carousel starts to "pop up" in weird places inside the body of the second carousel, or sometimes below it